# How long must I wait after Innocence Lost before the Dark Brotherhood kidnaps me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have completed the quest Innocence Lost and have waited for days, yet I have not received the letter from the Dark Brotherhood. Nor does sleeping for 24-day intervals work.

Is my game glitched, and if so is there a way to fix it, such as a console command to trigger the quest?

Comment: I was running into trouble getting the "Friends like these" quest to appear. For me the courier showed up soon after the assassination but I never got abducted and I had slept a few times. I realized that the note I received was stored in my house...for the abduction to occur the note must be carried by your character when you sleep. I know this doesn't help the original poster at all but I figured it may help someone else.

Answer (score 6):

Having completed the "Innocence Lost" quest, I immediately fast traveled to my house in Whiterun and slept for 1 hour, the kidnapping took place straight away, there was no delay.

It has been noted on the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/With_Friends_Like_These...#Notes) that:

> If the courier doesn't appear after waiting a few days, sleep in a bed
>   for at least 8 hours and the quest will continue.
>
> - Sometimes this can take several days, even with sleeping.
> - If the courier still does not appear, try fast traveling to a different hold and waiting.
> - Sleeping for at least 8 hours is not necessary. 5 hours continued the quest. (PC) 1 hour continued the quest. (Xbox 360) 1 hour worked
>     (PS3)

Just keep wandering around a different town and waiting until the courier arrives, it's been suggested this can take many days in game.

Answer (score 1):

about 24hours has always done it for me.. you cant go to sleep immediately.. If you wait overly long a courier will delivery a piece of paper to you with a black hand on it.

Comment: I think you have to receive the black hand before you sleep, iirc.

Comment: @Toast Nope.. Ive joined the brotherhood in 4 playthroughs, only got the black hand courier once.

Comment: Ive joined the brotherhood in almost every character i've played. Usually almost instantly after I kill Grelod. And I've never experienced this long of a delay which is why I'm kind of scared.

Comment: @hellfire I know if I go kill the lady, talk to the kid and then sleep immediately it will not happen.. if i go and sleep again though, it has always happened.. It just seemed like it needed a days delay or so.. Id say fast travel to another town and sleep there and see how it goes.

Comment: So far, I have waited about a week in in game time, before doing the 24 hour wait that you guys suggested. Then I went to sleep for 24 hours and still nothing yet. I have also traveled from white run, to riften to windhelm.

Answer (score 1):

PC Console workaround:

Locate the abandoned shack north of Morthal, south of the wreck of the icerunner. Once there, enter the following commands:

```
Setstage DB02 10
Player.additem 0002e3f8 1
```

This sets the quest with the objective to kill one of the prisoners and gives you the key necessary to enter the shack manually and do so. This is the only workaround that I know of, sorry Xbox people. If you get the glitch where the messenger doesn't show up there's no way to make him show up.